# Cannot access user with HttpContext

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm building and .Net-Core MVC project. The application provides a service called `CurrentUserService` (classic).
I access this service for example when I log and CRUD operation on an entity.

When I try to access the user by the `IHttpContextAccessor` he is not authenticatated even thought he is. And yes I did add `services.AddHttpContextAccessor();` to my service collection.

I created a contoller, accessed the `User` property and the user was authenticated. The following picture shows that:
[image]

Not sure what to do, Help.

**CurrentUserService**

```
public class CurrentUserService : ICurrentUserService
    {
        public CurrentUserService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            var user = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.User;
        
            if (user != null && user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                UserId = int.Parse(user.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.PrimarySid));
                IsAuthenticated = user.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
            }

        }

        public int UserId { get; }

        public bool IsAuthenticated { get; }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably problem with CurrentUserService itself. You are instantiating user in its constructor at which point you maybe don't have user authenticated.

I would try to change CurrentUserService like this:

```
public class CurrentUserService : ICurrentUserService
{
    private IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor;
    
    public CurrentUserService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        this.httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    private ClaimsPrincipal User => httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.User;

    public int UserId => User != null && User.Identity.IsAuthenticated ? int.Parse(User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.PrimarySid)) : 0;

    public bool IsAuthenticated => User != null && User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for great solution. It's worked for me. Why our way isn't working on constructor ?